# Why my checkbox in custom cell shows different behaviour while selecting and scrolling in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nib, custom-cell

I  have a xib view in which I took a `tableView` with a customcell xib. In this custom cell I have a checkbox  button which behaves like check and uncheck using custom cell. But when ever I click the first cell checkbox as tick the multiple of 9th cell like 9th row cell, 18th row cell, .....also became ticked. and while scrolling the checkbox tick option is changing between cells. I am not able to know why this is happening..??

I have registered cell xib view as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Register custom cell
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomOneCell", bundle: nil)
    AddOnTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "addoncell")
   }
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ADDONITEMS.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomOneCell = AddOnTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addoncell") as! CustomOneCell
    let item: AddOnItems = ADDONITEMS[indexPath.row]
            cell.addOnName.text = item.name
            cell.addOnPrice.text = "£\(item.price!)"


    return cell
}
```

For checkbox I have added  a custom class as below:

```
var isCheckedAddOnGlobal = Bool()
class AddOnCheckBox: UIButton {


let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checkboxredtick.png")! as UIImage
let unCheckedImage =  UIImage(named:"checkbox untick.png")!as UIImage

//bool property
var ischecked:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        //print(ischecked)
        if ischecked == true{
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)


        }else{
            self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.ischecked = false
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    if (sender == self) {
        if ischecked == true{
            ischecked = false
            isCheckedAddOnGlobal = false

        }else{
            ischecked = true
            isCheckedAddOnGlobal = true

        }

    }

    }
 }
```

Comment: why you are not using didSelectCell method instead of adding weird targets, just use buttonClicked in didSelectCell method, that will help

Comment: my button is in custom cell so I think I without adding target how could i set any action on button click if the cell contents are on another swift file with superclass  UITableViewCell@Lu_

Comment: check my answer, do not use cell as button, it has own methods on click and other actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are reusing the `TableViewCell`, To solve your problem you can try something like this, first create an array of Int that give you selected row and use that array inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
var selectedItems = [Int]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomOneCell = AddO nTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addoncell") as! CustomOneCell
    let item: AddOnItems = ADDONITEMS[indexPath.row]
    cell.addOnName.text = item.name
    cell.addOnPrice.text = "£\(item.price!)"
    cell.checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    if (selectedItems.contains(indexPath.row)) {
        cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"checkbox untick.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    else {
        cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxredtick.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
    cell.checkBoxBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
     if (self.selectedItems.contains(sender.tag)) {
          let index = self.selectedItems.indexOf(sender.tag)
          self.selectedItems.removeAtIndex(index)
     }
     else {
          self.selectedItems.append(sender.tag)
     }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: you have added all the button action at the same place itself. I want using the custom class for button..that I I have used  in my  code.

Comment: You can not done this by using your old method because that will not work with `UITableViewCell` when you reuse it.

Comment: code are working correct..  But I need to implement so many things based on selecting checkbox. so can you please make me understandable whats going on in  buttonClicked

Comment: On button click we are check that selected checkbox is already inside array or not, if it is inside means we need to uncheck it, so we are removing the object from array, if the array doesn't contains object means we need to check the button so we are adding row inside that array.

Comment: ok.  for example if i have to a set the checkbox selection based on some restrictions based on checkboxcount .. whre should i define it..see the old codes than you can able to understand..http://pastie.org/10925906

Comment: Welcome mate :) Good, Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

Best way is on selecting cell call

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomOneCell
    cell.buttonClicked()
}
```

and change buttonClicked method to

```
func buttonClicked() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make an object, which contains the product information and a boolean, to check if the product has been selected or not.

If you make it this way, the checkmarks will appear correct. When you are scrolling on a tableview, then it loads the data everytime it shows new cells.

Right now, it only knows that the index etc. 9 is selected, and when you scroll down and load new cells, then the index 9 will be selected automatic again.

Try something like this:

Example

```
class Product {
var productName = "Test"
var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

Under your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if product.isSelected == true {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"checkbox untick.png"), forState: .Normal)
} else {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkboxredtick.png"), forState: .Normal)
}
```

Comment: send some sample plz

Comment: Upload your project to github, it's much easier to help then

Comment: I have pasted a small example. Hope it will help you